# group the array by the same key and value and create json data with it

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [religion] => Christian
        [emp_count] => 4
        [b_name] => tripura
        [branch_id] => 7
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [religion] => Christian
        [emp_count] => 2
        [b_name] => Tirunelveli
        [branch_id] => 10
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [religion] => Christian
        [emp_count] => 4
        [b_name] => Madurai
        [branch_id] => 12
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [religion] => Hindu
        [emp_count] => 3
        [b_name] => tripura
        [branch_id] => 7
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [religion] => Hindu
        [emp_count] => 4
        [b_name] => Tirunelveli
        [branch_id] => 10
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [religion] => 
        [emp_count] => 0
        [b_name] => 
        [branch_id] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [religion] => 
        [emp_count] => 0
        [b_name] => 
        [branch_id] => 
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [religion] => Muslim
        [emp_count] => 1
        [b_name] => Tirunelveli
        [branch_id] => 10
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [religion] => 
        [emp_count] => 0
        [b_name] => 
        [branch_id] => 
    )

)
```

i need to group the array by the same key and value and create a json data with the grouped array.

For Eg: i need to display it as

```
{
name : 'Christian',
data :[4,2,4]
},
{name:'Hindu',
data:[3,2,1]
} ....
```

Comment: Create an loop and create your own data-array. But why you dont use only `json_encode`?

Comment: `data :[4,2,4]` where is this coming from your data source?

Comment: he need the array grouped by religion with array of emp_count

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to group the array by the same key and value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108584/how-to-group-the-array-by-the-same-key-and-value)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go!

- Create your own array
- Loop through your current array (`$arrArray`)
- Group elements, by adding them to `$arrGrouped`

#### The code

```
$arrGrouped = array();
foreach($arrArray as $arrElement) {
     if( array_key_exists($arrElement['religion'], $arrGrouped) ) {
        $arrGrouped[$arrElement['religion']] += $arrElement['emp_count'];
     } else {
        $arrGrouped[$arrElement['religion']] = $arrElement['emp_count'];
     }
}

echo '<pre>'. json_encode($arrGrouped, true) .'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in two steps:

1. Group the same religion together and gather the counts
2. Map the result into the final data array

So:

```
$result = array_reduce($array, function(&$result, $current) {
    $result[$current['religion']][] = $current['emp_count'];
    return $result;
}, []);

$data = [];
foreach ($result as $religion => $emp_counts) {
    $data[] = [
        'name' => $religion,
        'data' => $emp_counts,
    ];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

See: [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce) [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode)