# Group by a multidimensionnal array in PHP and concatenate results with comma (without creating unnecessary commas)

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation, grouping, delimited

I need to group rows in my two-dimensional array by two columns then within each group, I need to join another column's values with commas.

Notice that in the third row, the diagnostic value is empty.

```
$data = [
  ["id" => 1, "begin" => "01/01", "diagnostic" => "a"],
  ["id" => 1, "begin" => "01/01", "diagnostic" => "b"],
  ["id" => 1, "begin" => "01/01", "diagnostic" => ""],
  ["id" => 1, "begin" => "02/02", "diagnostic" => "a"],
];
```

Expected result:

```
[
  ["id" => 1, "begin" => "01/01", "diagnostic" => "a, b"],
  ["id" => 1, "begin" => "02/02", "diagnostic" => "a"],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, you are asking for a complete solution.

So here's my quick take on how to get it done:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eb4fef6146b77fb7ff157790046c79750ef90cdb

```
<?php
$data = [
  0 =>array("id"=>1, "begin"=>"01/01","diagnostic"=>"a", "procedure" => "x"),
  1 =>array("id"=>1, "begin"=>"01/01","diagnostic"=>"b", "procedure" => ""),
  2 =>array("id"=>1, "begin"=>"01/01","diagnostic"=>"a", "procedure" => "y"),
  3 =>array("id"=>1, "begin"=>"02/02","diagnostic"=>"a", "procedure" => "z"),
];

// create an empty array to hold results
$result = [];

// iterate through each entry of the original $data
foreach($data as $entry){
    // create a temporary array index, that will be unique across the entries conditions (begin, id)
    $tempId = $entry['id'] . '-' . $entry['begin'];

    // create and append entries to diagnostic and procedure
    $result[$tempId]['diagnostic'][] = $entry['diagnostic'];
    $result[$tempId]['procedure'][] = $entry['procedure'];

    // copy data that is identical
    $result[$tempId]['begin'] = $entry['begin'];
    $result[$tempId]['id'] = $entry['id'];
}

// iterate through entries and implode unique, not empty elements of diagnostic and procedure array with a comma
foreach($result as &$entry){
    $entry['diagnostic'] = implode(',', array_unique(array_filter($entry['diagnostic'])));
    $entry['procedure'] = implode(',', array_unique(array_filter($entry['procedure'])));
}
print_r($result);
```

The above will produce:

```
Array
(
    [1-01/01] => Array
        (
            [diagnostic] => a,b
            [procedure] => x,y
            [begin] => 01/01
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1-02/02] => Array
        (
            [diagnostic] => a
            [procedure] => z
            [begin] => 02/02
            [id] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

This task has a slight twist compared to the usual "group and append/concat" questions because you want to avoid writing unnecessary commas when an empty diagnostic value exists in a group.  The classic (best) approach is to use the two identifying row values to form a unique string and apply that string as the first level "grouping key" in the result array.

Every time a combination of `id` and `begin` values is encountered, the row data needs to be pushed into the group and correctly formatted.

The extra step, here, is that you must check the length of the current `diagnostic` value AND check the length of the group's `diagnostic` value to determine if a comma needs to be appended before the new value.

It doesn't take much imagination to understand that using a single loop is going to outperform using multiple loops and `array_column()` calls.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ITq52))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $compositeKey = $row['id'] . '-' . $row['begin'];
    if (!isset($result[$compositeKey])) {
        $result[$compositeKey] = $row;
    } elseif (strlen($row['diagnostic'])) {
        $result[$compositeKey]['diagnostic'] .= (strlen($result[$compositeKey]['diagnostic']) ? ', ' : '') . $row['diagnostic'];
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'begin' => '01/01',
    'diagnostic' => 'a, b',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'begin' => '02/02',
    'diagnostic' => 'a',
  ),
)
```